# Apache flip flops between default VHOSTs each reload

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

We have a CentOS 6 VM running apache with several virtual hosts.  One (and only one) of these was intermittently not working.

What I was seeing was that after an apache restart sometimes you get an index listing, other times you got our intranet site.  Even weirder - The example virtual host that gives you a directory list was disabled!  Even more strange was that the server aliases I have set up for the intranet site, always worked.

On CentOS 6 at least - apache is gracefully restarted automatically every so often.

The temporary fix to get our intranet site back - was to restart apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today (while musing what on earth could be the problem) I ran

```
apachectl -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

several times in a row and I noticed that the default vhost for port 443 was flip flopping between two host names.  One was not even a vhost name.

I did a reverse dig on the server's ip address.

```
dig -x 1.2.3.4
```

And lo and behold, two 'A' records returned.  One for our intranet site, one for the server host name we use to ssh into it etc.

Changing one of those to be a CNAME like it should have been seems to have corrected the issue.  The server is no longer having an identity crisis.